# JavaScript split string by positive lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string including the delimeters, so for example

- `"a/b/c"` would become `["a/", "b/", "c"]`
- `"a//b"` would become `["a/", "/", "b"]`

```js
var s = "a/b/c".split(/(?<=\/)/);

console.log(s); // prints ["a/", "b/", "c"]
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome, but Firefox says: `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`

Hence my questions:

1. Is the code legal?
2. How to make it work in Firefox and Edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Firefox supports lookbehinds yet. Instead, you can split using a capture group to retain the delimiter, match any preceding characters that are not forward slashes within the group, and then filter to remove the empty strings. For example:

```js
const s = 'a/b/c'.split(/([^/]*\/)/).filter((x) => x);
console.log(s);
// ["a/", "b/", "c"]
```

```js
const s = 'a//b'.split(/([^/]*\/)/).filter((x) => x);
console.log(s);
// ["a/", "/", "b"]
```

Answer (score 1):

(a) it looks like most browsers don't yet support lookbehind; Chrome is one of the few that do (as of 2019-Jun)
[source: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions ]

(b) I would tend to simply split by `/\//`, and know that every element but the last should "really" have a trailing slash.  `"a/b//c//".split(/\//)` returns `["a","b","","c","",""]`.

(c) You could also do a `match` (rather than `split`) on "slash, followed by 0-or-more-non-slashes: `"a/b//c//".match(/[^\/]*\//g)` returns `["a/","b/","/","c/","/"]`.

Btw, be sure to test your solution on strings that start with a "/" (which should presumably return just `"/"` as the very first element).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that thing doesn't work in rest of the browsers. But you can use following trick with `replace`:

```
var text = 'a/b/c';
var splitText = text
    .replace(new RegExp(/\//, 'g'), '/ ') // here you are replacing your leading slash `/` with slash + another symbol e.g. `/ `(space is added) 
    .split(' ') // to further split with added symbol as far as they are removed when splitting.
 console.log(splitText) // ["a/", "b/", "c"]
```

In this way you can avoid using that complex regExp which doesn't work in FireFox, Edge etc.

Comment: What if the source string contains spaces? Won't it be better to split by `/` and then re-add them?

Comment: can just use another symbol but space